# Searching mongoose with Model.find and a RegExp in TypeScript. Getting error: 'Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'string''

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm converting my express server to typescript and I'm having trouble with a type error. Below is a search function using mongoose. It takes a RegExp, and then calls `Model.find()`.

```
export const search = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const { value } = req.query;
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    const regExp = new RegExp(value, 'i');
    try {
      const results = await Product.find({ $text: { $search: regExp } }).exec();
    // etc.
    }
```

The error is on `$search` and says `No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

I think this means that the function doesn't allow RegExps, but I know it worked fine in plain js.

Comment: try this { "fieldName" : { $regex:regex, $options: 'i' }}.  first argument is field name, second is regular expression, third is for case insensitive match

Comment: @Nonik sorry, where should I put this? in the Product.find?

Comment: yes, Product.find({ "fieldName" : { $regex:regex, $options: 'i' }}).exec();

Comment: did you solve this issue? i am having the same issue and cannot figure out how to solve it/

Comment: @auryn31 IIRC, I just did what Nonik suggested and it to worked. The only problem I had was I could only search 1 field (in the old way, I could search several)